# Fetching repetitive character from string list in python

Tags: python

I have a list containing some strings starting with similar letters. The list is  `["flower","flow","flight"]`. Here i want to return the string `fl` as output since `fl` is contained in  the three words in the list.

In this case i have tried to take the count of the words and add up to dictionary and print the key which contains the maximum value. Here is the code i have tried.

```
from collections import Counter
alist = ["flower","flow","flight"]
count = {}
length = len(alist)


c = Counter(alist)
for letter in c.elements():

 for s in letter:
     
     if s in count:
         
         count[s] += 1
         maxi  = max(count.values())
         if count[s] == maxi:
             print(s)
         
    
     else:
         count[s] = 1
```

When the above code executes it gives me an output of `flow and fl` which is not the dezired output i needed. Can someone help me through this?. Is there a better and simple way to acheive this without using the dictionary. Am a newbie in python. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow your code, but it looks like you're trying to find the longest common prefix of a list of words.  Check out: [Longest Common Prefix — Solving with 10+ Methods using Python](https://medium.com/@d_dchris/10-methods-to-solve-the-longest-common-prefix-problem-using-python-leetcode-14-a87bb3eb0f3a)

Comment: @DarrylG This is exactly what i was looking for..Many thanx mate